# UnicodeDecodeError in django top-level template code

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have code in my views that returns information to be displayed in a textbox. My name has fadas (Irish accent) over the letters which is causing UnicodeDecodeErrors. The line in my logic is as follows:

```
return {
    ...
    'wrap_up_form': WrapUpForm(data={u'message': settings.DEFAULT_WRAP_UP_MESSAGE.format(name=customer.given_name.encode('utf-8'))}),
}
```

and the traceback I get is this

```
ERROR    2014-07-24 14:48:26,540 exception_handlers.py:65] 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rony/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/rony/Documents/clone-attempt/personal-shopping/vendor/nacelle/core/dispatcher.py", line 24, in nacelle_dispatcher
    response = router.default_dispatcher(request, response)
  File "/home/rony/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/rony/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1065, in __call__
    return self.handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rony/Documents/clone-attempt/personal-shopping/app/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _arguments_wrapper
    return view_method(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rony/Documents/clone-attempt/personal-shopping/app/utils/decorators.py", line 89, in _arguments_wrapper
    output = render_jinja2_template(template_name, context)
  File "/home/rony/Documents/clone-attempt/personal-shopping/vendor/nacelle/core/template/renderers.py", line 19, in render_jinja2_template
    return renderer.render_template(template_name, **context)
  File "/home/rony/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2_extras/jinja2.py", line 158, in render_template
    return self.environment.get_template(_filename).render(**context)
  File "/home/rony/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "templates/cms/appointments_form.html", line 2, in top-level template code
    {% import 'cms/macros.html' as cms_macros %}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Do I need to add some sort of encoding to my templates?

Comment: What happen if you remove `.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: I now get a UnicodeEncodeError: gist.github.com/anonymous/e06491e967638cb44e3e

Comment: What if you use `decode` instead of `encode`?

Comment: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Could you show the line that contains `DEFAULT_WRAP_UP_MESSAGE` in the settings file?

Comment: DEFAULT_WRAP_UP_MESSAGE = """Hey {name},

We hope you have enjoyed the Hangout with us and that we will see you again soon!
We've added the collections we looked at here for you.

All the best,
Personal Shopping
"""

Comment: Try to change the literal to unicode literal (`DEFAULT_WRAP_UP_MESSAGE = u"""Hey {name}, We ...."""`). (and remove `decode(..)` from the line that cause the error)

Comment: Excellent! Wanna put that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: I put answer. Feel free to edit my answer if sentences does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman answered, I also suspect that `customer.given_name` is byte string; trying to `encode` on it cause Python try to decode it.

Another issue is that `DEFAULT_WRAP_UP_MESSAGE` is byte string literal.

`str.format(unicode)` has same issue.

---

Solution:

- remove `.decode(..)` part.
- Make a DEFAULT_WRAP_UP_MESSAGE unicode object instead of byte string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that `customer.given_name` is a byte string, rather than Unicode - so in calling `encode` on it, Python first needs to decode it to Unicode before it can then re-encode to UTF-8.

You should drop the encode call altogether.

Comment: I now get a `UnicodeEncodeError`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e06491e967638cb44e3e